# Including dependent dlls in web part

Tags: web-part

I have a C# dll that is a wrapped C++ dll which has multiple dependencies. I have tested the new C# dll in a project and the dll works properly. I now need to use the C# dll in a custom web part. I have added the C# reference to the project but how do I add all the C++ dlls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify additional assemblies to add to a WSP by going to the Package in Visual Studio (double click) and navigating to the Advanced Tab. There you'll see an Additional Assemblies tool - just specify the path to the DLL to include and make sure you deploy it to the GAC if necessary.